# Or Condition in a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in which I need to get the value between either `"[ValueToBeFetched]"` or `"{ValueToBeFetched}"`.

```
var test = "I am \"{now}\" doing \"[well]\"";

test.match(/"\[.*?]\"/g)
```

the above regex serves the purpose and gets the value between square brackets and I can use the same for curly brackets also.

```
test.match(/"\{.*?}\"/g)
```

Is there a way to keep only one regex and do this, something like an `or` `{|[` operator in regex.
I tried some scenarios but they don't seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _" I tried some scenarios but they don't seem to work."_ - You've forgotten to add at least one of those "scenarios" and an explanation why you think it "doesn't work" and what this means exactly -> [mcve]

Comment: You can use `/"[\[\{].*?[\]\}]"/g` but this will also search `[some}`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Can however do `/"\[(.*)\]"|"\{(.*)\}"/`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte It looks to work, it only remains to add flag `g`

Comment: @ASDFGerte breaks on line `"I am \"{now}\" doing \"[well]\" fasfa \"[fsafa}\""` :(

Comment: oof in the hurry i did the basic mistake of using `.*` instead of the respective `[^\]]*` and `[^\}]*`. I should not write comments, while doing three other things - only leads to stupid mistakes. Use `"\[([^\]]*)\]"|"\{([^\}]*)\}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try following regex:

```
(?:{|\[).*?(?:}|\])
```

Details:

- `(?:{|\[)`: Non-capturing group, gets character { or [
- `.*?`: gets as few as possible
- `(?:}|\])`: Non-capturing group, gets character } or ]

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RSXYDA/1)

Code in JavaScript:

```
var test = "I am \"{now}\" doing \"[well]\"";

var result = test.match(/"(?:{|\[).*?(?:}|\])"/g);
console.log(result);
```

Result:

```
["{now}", "[well]"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there is an `or` operator which is `|`:

**[Edited as suggested]** Let's catch all sentences that begins with an "a" or a "b" :

```
/^((a|b).*)/gm
```

In this example, if the line parsed begins with a or b, the entire sentence will be catched in the first result group.

You may test your regex with [an online regex tester](https://regex101.com/)

For your special case, try something like that, and use the online regex tester i mentionned before to understand how it works:

```
((\[|\{)\w*(\]|\}))
```

Comment: Either use `(a|b)` or `[ab]` but not what you currently have. What you have will literally match `a` or `|` or `b`.